# Colision de circulos

Tags: python, class, pygame

realizo un programa donde genero circulos de tamaño y posicion aleatoria, por medio de clases en python, e logrado generar los circulos como lo deseo, asi que e utilice un metodo para que eso no suceda, agradeceria consejos para mejorar

mi codigo es el siguiente.
primero mi clase circulo donde contengo el metodo de colision:

```
class Circulo(PosGeo):
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radio = r
        self.cx = x+r
        self.cy = y+r

    def dibujar(self, ventana):
        pg.draw.circle(ventana, "white", (self.cx, self.cy), self.radio, 1)

    def update(self):
        pass

    def colisionC(self, c2):
        return self.radio + c2.radio > sqrt(pow(self.cx - c2.cx, 2) + pow(self.cy - c2.cy, 2))
```

ahora una parte de mi codigo main, concretamente donde dibujo los circulos de posicion y tamaño aleatorio:

```
class CreaCir:
    def __init__(self, figs):
        self.figs = figs

    def update(self):
        if len(self.figs) <100:
            choca = False
            r = randint(5, 104)
            x = randint(0, 500 + r)
            y = randint(0, 300 + r) 
            creOne = Circulo(x, y, r)
            for  fig in (self.figs):
                choca = creOne.colisionC(fig)
                if choca == True:
                    break
            if choca == False:
                figs.append(creOne)
               

    def dibujar(self, ventana):
        pass
```

y por ultimo mi ventana y el llamado la clase :

```
class Ventana:
    def __init__(self, Ven_Tam= (700, 500)):
        
        pg.init()
        self.ven_tam = Ven_Tam

        self.ven = pg.display.set_caption("Linea")
        self.ven = pg.display.set_mode(self.ven_tam)
        self.ven.fill(pg.Color('#404040'))
        self.figs = []
        self.reloj = pg.time.Clock()
        
    def check_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT or (event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
                quit()
        pg.display.flip()

    def run(self):
        CirCreate = CreaCir(self.figs)
        while True:
            self.check_events()
            CirCreate.update(


            for fig in self.figs:
                fig.dibujar(self.ven)

            self.reloj.tick(60)
                 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ven = Ventana()
    ven.run()
```

Comment: Está bien claro que la clase `CreaCir` no tiene un método "radio" (lo tiene la clase `Circulo`). Estás pasando un objeto del tipo incorrecto. El código publicado está incompleto y no hay más que decir.

Comment: @CandidMoe por que incompleto?

Comment: Código completo: lo puedes copiar y ejecutar sin más, que no es el caso aquí. Sólo has proporcionado dos clases sin ningun código que las llame.

Comment: @CandidMoe oh lo demas no lo proporcione porque no me genera ningun problema pero si se nececita lo edito

Comment: Aparte de lo anterior, hay problemas de lógica por todas partes. Por ejemplo, en el `CrearCir.__init__()` inicializas una cantidad de variables locales que no utlizas para nada. Recibe una variable `figs` que tampoco guardas y que intentas usar en `update()`.

Comment: Quedo a la espera de un ejemplo mínimo completo y ejecutable.

Comment: @CandidMoe ya encontre el problema, ya es ejecutable tal cual lo tengo en mi pregunta, pero colisionan

Comment: Si encontraste el problema y lo arreglaste, la pregunta no tiene sentido tal cual puesto que tu problema ahora es otro y no el que indicas. O respondes a la pregunta tú mismo (o la borras si quieres, pero no la dejes abierta y sin respuesta por favor!) o la editas para que refleje la realidad... no somos adivinos y cada pregunta debe tener una única respuesta, esto no es un foro donde abras un tema para que te solucionemos cada problema que tienes. Cada pregunta debe ser sobre un único problema!

Comment: @Benito-B lo siento, mi intencion no fue molestar, tal cual no hice otra pregunta, solo hice una afirmacion, en un rato la edito para no dejarla abierta, aclarar que soy nuevo asi que tengo errores en la pagina, no era necesario el lenguaje poco amistoso, se entender, asi que lo repito, lo siento

Comment: faltaba el check de circulo dentro de otro ?

Comment: @aloMalbarez, no, lo que pasa es que agregue la clase **Crearcir** a la lista y quite cosas que sobraban